# .Net Asymmetric Encryption on a file 1 to 32 KB

Tags: .net, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to asymmetric encryption on a file 1 to 32 KBytes and am running into exceptions being thrown becase of the size when I use the .Net classes.
I can do it for a file or key size that is in the 100 byte range without problems.
Thanks,
Allen

Comment: Post code that is failing

Comment: (In general) The size of data that can be encrypted using an asymmetric algorithm is limited by the size of its corresponding key (i.e. much less than 32kb), it's not designed to encrypt large blobs of data.  Instead encrypt the *data* using a symmetric algorithm (AES et al) and then encrypt the *symmetric key* with your private key.